# Polymorphic Ruby SimpleDelegator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, delegates, polymorphism

What are the alternatives to the `SimpleDelegator` to leverage polymorphism without modifying underlying object.

This is an example and the problem that `SimpleDelegator` doesn't solve.

The aim is to be able to wrap the original object (`delicious_food`) with any other (`yak_food`) so that the substituted method (`delicious?`) depends on the non-substituted methods of the underlying.

```
class Food
  def initialize(color)
    @color = color
  end

  def delicious?
    color == :red
  end

  def color
    @color
  end
end

class FoodTasteOverride < SimpleDelegator
  def color
    :green
  end
end

delicious_food = Food.new(:red)
yak_food = FoodTasteOverride.new delicious_food

delicious_food.delicious? # true - expected
yak_food.delicious? # expecting false, but is true since the color come from delicious_food
```

What would be the alternative that would actually use the substituted method? The contraint is that you can't modify the underlying object, its class or clone.

The constraint implies that you can't do this:

```
yak_food = delicious_food.clone
def yak_food.color
  :green
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative is to extend your instance's method using extend. (This is what most DCI implementations do to extend objects with behaviors at runtime)

```
class Food

  attr_reader :color

  def initialize(color)
    @color = color
  end

  def delicious?
    self.color == :red
  end

end

module FoodTasteOverride
  def color
    :green
  end
end


normal_food = Food.new(:red)
delicious_food = Food.new(:red)
yak_food = normal_food.extend(FoodTasteOverride)

puts delicious_food.delicious? # true - expected
puts yak_food.delicious? #false because the color is now green.
```

Comment: Using modules in this case seems more reasonable to me as well. Decorators are not supposed to change the internals.

Comment: Great idea. Didn't think about `extend` for some reason.